# How is it called when audio streaming "freezes" or "stucks"?

Tags: video-streaming, audio-streaming, terminology, firewire, runtime-error

How is it called when streaming (e.g. FireWire streaming) of video or audio stucks (or freezes) after about 10 minutes and I need to reset the streaming process (or reset the FireWire bus) to make it work again?

May I call it a "streaming freeze"?

Answer (score 0):

It is called an "end of stream error". The connection is lost (due to network congestion or an internal issue) and the streaming buffer is reset.

**References**

- [Real Time Streaming Protocol (RTSP) 2.0 Parameters](http://www.iana.org/assignments/rtspv2-parameters/rtspv2-parameters.xhtml)
- [Logging Model for Windows Media Services](https://www.microsoft.com/windows/windowsmedia/howto/articles/LoggingModel.aspx)
- [Input and Output: File System Information, Reading, Writing, and Streams](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36757/Input-and-Output-File-System-Information-Reading-W)
- [DMR state after finding an error (ERROR-01)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh997766.aspx)